# When I try to change a label to a pre-determined value and the result from a text field, it displays the text field information

Tags: swift2

I am trying to create a generator for AutoModerator on OS X, but when I try to change the value of a label, to the input of a text field, it doesn't display the data that was inputed, it displays other information.

My code is below

```
 // Text Fields

@IBOutlet weak var date: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var timezone: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var sticky: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var textFeild: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var textFeild2: NSTextField!
// Labels

@IBOutlet weak var timeDateTZone: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var stickyTrueFalse: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var titleResult: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var textResult: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var textResult2: NSTextField!

// Button

@IBAction func generateButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    print ("Generate Pressed")

    timeDateTZone.stringValue = ("first: \"\(date) \(timezone)\"")

    stickyTrueFalse.stringValue = ("sticky: \(sticky)")

    titleResult.stringValue = ("title: \"\(titleTextField)\"")

    textResult.stringValue = ("\(textFeild)")

    textResult2.stringValue = ("\(textFeild2)")
```

When I press the button, it displays this instead

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqoMv.png)

If anyone could help, that would be amazing.

Background about the app: It is a generator for AutoModerator on reddit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing the `NSTextField` instances directly (`\(...)`) will yield the result you show in your screenshot, and we need to access the actual text in the text field, rather than the information of the instance itself.

The `NSTextField` doesn't have a `.text` property (like e.g. `UILabel`), but it does have a `.stringValue` that you can use (inherited from `NSControl`). I see above that you *do* make use of this property when *setting* the value of the text fields `timeDateTZone`, `stickyTrueFalse` etc, but you need to also make use of this when you *extract* the string value from text fields `date`, `timezone` and so on.

Try placing adding the `.stringValue` suffix also to the `NSTextField` instances you want to read from:

```
@IBAction func generateButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    print ("Generate Pressed")

    timeDateTZone.stringValue = ("first: \"\(date.stringValue) \(timezone.stringValue)\"")

    stickyTrueFalse.stringValue = ("sticky: \(sticky.stringValue)")

    titleResult.stringValue = ("title: \"\(titleTextField.stringValue)\"")

    textResult.stringValue = ("\(textFeild.stringValue)")

    textResult2.stringValue = ("\(textFeild2.stringValue)")
}
```

---

> **Declaration** - stringValue
>
> ```
> var stringValue: String
> ```
>
> Returns the value of the receiver’s cell as an NSString object.

See

- [NSControl Class Reference - Getting and Setting the Control’s Value](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/stringValue)

and note that you can ask for other object returns than `NSString`, using other `NSControl` properties such as, e.g., `.intValue` (`var intValue: Int32`) or `.objectValue` (`@NSCopying var objectValue: AnyObject?`).